# Vlocity Document Template (Omnistudio) Showing text with % %

Tags: document-template, omnis-studio-10

I need to pull in text into the vlocity document template from a field in an salesforce object that looks - SBP 100%/70% with Comprehensive Rx Copay

however, the text with the % % symbols are not showing and the output on the template is like this - Customized SBP 100 with Comprehensive Rx Copay

Need solution to fix this